# jquery.forms plugin - send form to webmethod in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm trying to send my form to a web method in asp.net page using jquery.forms plugin (primary reason for that is that I need to send files as well).

However, I can't make it work - it returns the whole page all the time.

I use the following client-side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxUploadOptions = {
        beforeSubmit: UploadFormValidate,  // pre-submit callback 
        success: FormUploadSuccess,  // post-submit callback 
        error: FormUploadFailure,

        url: "Default.aspx/UploadFiles",         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        type: "POST",        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        dataType: "json",        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
    };

    function FormUploadSuccess(response, statusText, xhr, jqForm) {
        alert(response);
    };
    function FormUploadFailure(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
        alert(errorThrown);
    }

    $("form[id $= 'form1']").ajaxForm(ajaxUploadOptions);

  });
</script>
```

Code for the asp.net method just to return anything:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string UploadFiles()
    {
        return "Test";            
    }
```

I registered ScriptModule in web.config (also verified just calling regular jquery's $.ajax to make sure the method is available).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I haven't read documentation/code carefully enough. Found out that when sending files, the forms plugin uses iframe and regular submit.